# How to use Dropbox Sync API enumerations in Swift?

Tags: swift, dropbox-api, enumeration

Given a DBFile object, I kept getting compiler errors if I tried to compare the DBFileState to the enumerated values, e.g.

```
var file : DBFile = <some file>
var state = file.status.state
if state == DBFileStateUploading { do something }
```

The compiler error would say that '==' cannot compare (DBFileState, DBFileState)

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be quite simple:

```
if state.value == DBFileStateUploading.value { do something }
```

This has something to do with the fact the the Dropbox enumerations are imported C-style enumerations, but this wasn't easy to find.

Just thought I'd share to help anyone else that might be struggling with this.